# chrome 83 started crashing since upgrade

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Since the upgrade my angular e2e tests started failing with following message.

I am using `directConnect: true` and all my tests are using async/await. 
It looks it is crashing and does not always crash at the same point in my tests - and I do have some test running successfully. Disabled sharding as well.

`- Failed: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
           from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
           from tab crashed
             (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.61)
             (Driver info: chromedriver=83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 x86_64)`

**UPDATE: 6/1/2020**
After adding more shared memory (finding CI runners that have more memory) this problem is gone. Still leaves the problem in a "mystery mode".

**Update 6/2/2020:**

**Chrome Flags**

```
    'headless',
    'verbose',
    'w3c=false',
    'disable-infobars',
    'window-size=1440x1080',
    'disable-dev-shm-usage',
    'disable-gpu',
    'incognito',
    'disable-extensions',
    'disable-plugins',
    'no-sandbox'
```

Comment: any update? kinda frustrated already..

Comment: I had to add more shared memory to my test runner instances but what causes this problem is still a mystery

Comment: how do you shared memory? i tried shm_size:2g or dev/shm things, no one work.

Comment: After update up to v83 we met another problem, we receive "unable to connect to renderer" error. Have you faced it and how did you solve it?

Comment: @AnyChartSupport I haven seen "unable to connect to renderer" since long ago - can't recall but one of the chromes flags must have fixed it. I updated my post with the chromeflags.

Comment: Thanks @bhantol Adding  "disable-dev-shm-usage" in chrome option.
Chrome is not crashing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using chrome headless in podman and I've run into the same issue, here's what seems to work for me:

1. increase /dev/shm
2. remove "disable-dev-shm-usage" option

I needed the option in the past because it was impossible to change default /dev/shm size in a proprietary cloud software I'm using, looks like it's broken in the last chrome release.
The funny thing is - chrome also runs much faster after the changes

Comment: will try removing `disable-dev-shm-usage`

Answer (score 3):

same here, after every update they want us to suffer, to find a pass to buddhism